# Save and update dropdown "selected" option

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a form that includes a dropdown. On submit, I'm attempting to save the "selected" option so that on future page loads, this value is "selected" as default.

Something along the lines of:

```
<select name="people">
  <option value="person-1" <?php if($selected=="person-1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Person 1</option>
  <option value="person-2" <?php if($selected=="person-2") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Person 2</option>
  <option value="person-3" <?php if($selected=="person-3") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Person 3</option>
</select>
```

I assume the best way to achieve this would be with a MySQL database to save the selected option. I'm just unsure of how to go about this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: do you want to save in database or in client side?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I assume the best way to achieve this would be with a MySQL database to save the selected option."*

The answer to this is "yes".

What you need to do first, is to save the respective data in a database for the given row(s).

An example of this would be, and applying the same for the other values:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col) VALUES ('person-1')
```

Then retrieve it in a SELECT such as, and for example:

```
SELECT col, col_2, col_3 FROM TABLE
```

depending on how many columns you need to use/query with.

I.e. of a ternary operator and fetching over successful results with a `while` loop.

```
echo '

<select name="people">
  <option value="person-1" '.($row["col"] == "person-1" ? "selected" : "") .'>Person 1</option>
  <option value="person-2" '.($row["col"] == "person-2" ? "selected" : "") .'>Person 2</option>
  <option value="person-3" '.($row["col"] == "person-3" ? "selected" : "") .'>Person 3</option>
</select>

';
```

Or, you can use what you presently are using in the `<options>`. You would need to use the `$selected` variable inside the loop, yet I find that the ternary operator is easier to use for cases like this.

Example of a `while` loop, and I used the MySQLi_ API here:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

The dropdown's name attribute could be used in a form using either a POST or GET method, the choice is yours.

You will need to choose the MySQL API of your liking, but keep in mind that the `MySQL_*` functions/API is deprecated and deleted as of PHP 7.0

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

---

*Footnotes:*

I believe I have given you enough to get you started. I don't usually give answers for questions like these since they are rather broad, yet I found that if I could be of help, then great.

- It was also too long to be posted as a comment.

You should also read up on using prepared statements since you seem to be new in working with databases.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Other references:

- Dealing with forms http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
- INSERT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html
- SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html